# How to define a function that returns the derivative to be later passed in a lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, derivative

Consider the following Python code

```py
def Hubble_a(a):
    ...
    return

def t_of_a(a):
    res = np.zeros_like(a) 
    for i,ai in enumerate(a):
        t,err = quad(lambda ap : 1.0/(ap*Hubble_a(ap)),0,ai) 
        res[i] = t
        return res

a = np.logspace(-8,1,100)
```

What I want to do is to define a function `Hubble_a(a)` that gives the derivative of `a` divided by `a`, in order to integrate over it with `quad`. I tried to define it in this way:

```py
def Hubble_a(a):
    da = diff(a,1)
    da_over_a = da/a
    return da_over_a
```

where `diff` is the FFT derivative imported from `scipy.fftpack`. Then, if I execute `t_of_a(a)` I get a `object of type 'float' has no len()` error, presumably because `quad` doesn't take arrays? However I don't think this definition makes any sense in the first place because I want to pass a function such that `lambda` maps to `1.0/(ap*Hubble_a(ap)` and know I'm passing the derivative of an *array* instead of a function that can then by integrated over. **So I'm looking for help on how to implement a function that maps to something like `(da/dt)/a`**.